# unable to import dlib in python

Tags: python, macos, boost-python, dlib

I successfully installed dlib for python, following instructions [here](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/03/27/how-to-install-dlib/). However, when I try to import the library I get this message:

```
  >>> import dlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dlib/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .dlib import *
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dlib/dlib.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libpng16.16.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dlib/dlib.so
  Reason: image not found
```

I previously had(and uninstalled) anaconda and had the same issue in python 3.6. Looking at similar [questions](https://github.com/davisking/dlib/issues/274) and responses it sounds like I would have to use  `install_name_tool` command. However I do not know what the new path would be. I do not quite understand why this is necessary either. From what I know, the path that was referenced should have been fine. Why will dlib not import and what can I do to make it import successfully? Let me know. Thanks

Comment: The error tells you whats the problem. You are missing **libpng**, or you were missing it during install-config. So this really looks not like an successful install. Double check!

Comment: I moved libpng from its default place and this problem seems to be fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I would call this a solution, since I still have issues, but what I did was: `install_name_tool -change @rpath/libpng16.16.dylib "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/dlib/dlib.so" /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dlib/dlib.so`

Although there was an additional problem with my installation, this fixed the problem at hand. I had dlib in my default python library rather than with a path similar to one in my virtual machine. So I changed the path to fit my VM and all my other installation packages(e.g boost and cmake)