# unable to import dlib in python(and restarting installation?)

Tags: python, macos, dependencies, libpng, dlib

I previously had the same issue with a different error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46043894/unable-to-import-dlib-in-python) and thought it would be appropriate to ask a separate question.

```
 import dlib
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dlib/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .dlib import *
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dlib/dlib.so, 2): Library not loaded: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/dlib/dlib.so
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dlib/dlib.so
  Reason: Incompatible library version: dlib.so requires version 44.0.0 or later, but dlib.so provides version 0.0.0
```

I am almost certain this is because after I used `install_name_tool -id "@loader_path/opt/X11/lib/libpng16.16.dylib" /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dlib/dlib.so`
(which was not what resolved my previous error) `otool -L /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dlib/dlib.so` stopped returning this:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dlib/dlib.so:
@rpath/dlib.so (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
/usr/local/opt/boost-python/lib/libboost_python-mt.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
/opt/X11/lib/libSM.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.1.0)
/opt/X11/lib/libICE.6.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.0.0)
/opt/X11/lib/libX11.6.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.0.0)
/opt/X11/lib/libXext.6.dylib (compatibility version 11.0.0, current version 11.0.0)
@rpath/libpng16.16.dylib (compatibility version 44.0.0, current version 44.0.0)
@rpath/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.8)
@rpath/libmkl_rt.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
@rpath/libsqlite3.0.dylib (compatibility version 9.0.0, current version 9.6.0)
/usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 307.5.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1238.60.2)
```

and started returning this:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dlib/dlib.so:
@loader_path/opt/X11/lib/libpng16.16.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
/usr/local/opt/boost-python/lib/libboost_python-mt.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
/opt/X11/lib/libSM.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.1.0)
/opt/X11/lib/libICE.6.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.0.0)
/opt/X11/lib/libX11.6.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.0.0)
/opt/X11/lib/libXext.6.dylib (compatibility version 11.0.0, current version 11.0.0)
@rpath/libpng16.16.dylib (compatibility version 44.0.0, current version 44.0.0)
@rpath/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.8)
@rpath/libmkl_rt.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
@rpath/libsqlite3.0.dylib (compatibility version 9.0.0, current version 9.6.0)
/usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 307.5.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1238.60.2)
```

After 'resolving' my previous path error with `install_name_tool -change @rpath/libpng16.16.dylib "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/dlib/dlib.so" /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dlib/dlib.so` I got this:

```
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dlib/dlib.so:
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/dlib/dlib.so (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
/usr/local/opt/boost-python/lib/libboost_python-mt.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
/opt/X11/lib/libSM.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.1.0)
/opt/X11/lib/libICE.6.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.0.0)
/opt/X11/lib/libX11.6.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.0.0)
/opt/X11/lib/libXext.6.dylib (compatibility version 11.0.0, current version 11.0.0)
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/dlib/dlib.so (compatibility version 44.0.0, current version 44.0.0)
@rpath/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.8)
@rpath/libmkl_rt.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
@rpath/libsqlite3.0.dylib (compatibility version 9.0.0, current version 9.6.0)
/usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 307.5.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1238.60.2)
```

I do not know what is required to make my `dlib.co` path and file compatible, and if I cannot do anything about this I am willing to reinstall everything, but I do not know what I would have to do differently next time. How could I restart this process? I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling several dependencies(cmake, boost, boost-python, libpng, dlib). I have also tried restoring the paths back to what they were with: `install_name_tool -id "libpng16.16.dylib"  @loading_path/opt/X11/lib/libpng16.16.dylib` but I do not know how relevant that is and no longer understand what I am doing.

What can I do from here to successfully install dlib?